# Appending data to an anchor tag

Tags: php, html

i am new to PHP , i want to append data like query string and data i will recieve by `$_GET[]` or `$_POST[]`, but have facing a problem

i have done something like this `<a href="?ref=login_detail?id=<?php echo $car_id; ?>">Hello</a>`

this `?ref=login_detail` is a function which navigate me to another page. How can I pass `$car_id`  to anchor tag so that is available in another page?

Here is function

```
public function login_detail(){

    include('display/car_detail.php');

}
```

Comment: @Sundar you also right but first i need to append it , but i was making syntactical misakte

Answer (score 2):

First of all - only first parameter in URL should be prefixed will `?`, every other should be prefixed with `&`.

So your URL should look like:

```
<a href="?ref=login_detail&id=<?php echo $car_id ?>">Hello</a>
```

Note the `&` instead of second `?`.

After this, in the *target* script (which is probably `index.php`) you can catch your `$car_id` using:

```
var_dump($_GET['id']);
```

This should print the `$car_id` you pass to it by clicking the link.

---

Going further, depending on your architecture you can change your method to accept some parameters like this:

```
class Obj
{
    public function login_detail($id)
    {
        //do something with passed $id
        echo $id;
    }
}

(...)
$obj = new Obj();
$obj->login_detail($_GET['id']);
```

or just use it within the method itself:

```
class Obj
{
    public function login_detail($id)
    {
        echo $_GET['id'];
    }
}
$obj = new Obj();
$obj->login_detail();
```

Comment: thanx alot .Its working and i am getting the $car_id ,now i am going to use  it in a query

Comment: look what i have done in car_detail.php page `$id = $_GET['id'];
    $result=$this->mlogin->cars_detail($id);
    echo $id;
    
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);` and my model code is `public function cars_detail($id){

        $this->select_query="SELECT * FROM `_cars` WHERE `_id`='$id'";

        return $this->select();



    }
    `

Comment: then i echo the respective data into the table .i thank you again to you and all whom help me